# Hudson trigger build periodic event Poll SCM is selected

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I configured Hudson with clearcase and able to trigger build when any checkin is happened on branch but the real issue i am facing was after triggering the build then build is happening on every 1 minute periodically

I want to avoid this periodic build and need only one build when any checkin happens

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To poll every 1 minute, your cron should look like:

`*/1 * * * *`